# Correct join of DataFrame in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am new in **Spark Framework** and need some help!

Assume that the first DataFrame (`df1`) stores the time that users access the call center.

```
+---------+-------------------+
|USER_NAME|       REQUEST_DATE|
+---------+-------------------+
|     Mark|2018-02-20 00:00:00|
|     Alex|2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|      Bob|2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|     Mark|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
|     Kate|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
+---------+-------------------+
```

The second DataFrame stores information about whether a person is a member of the organization. `OUT` means that the user has left the organization. `IN` means that the user has come to the organization. `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` mean the beginning and end of the corresponding process.

For example, you can see that `Alex` left the organization  at `2018-01-01 00:00:00`, and this process ended at `2018-02-01 00:00:00`. You can notice that one user can come and left the organization at different times as `Mark`.

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|NAME     | START_DATE          | END_DATE            | STATUS |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|     Alex| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
|      Bob| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-05 00:00:00 | IN     |
|     Mark| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | IN     |
|     Mark| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | 2018-08-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
|    Meggy| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
+----------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to get such a DataFrame in the final. It must contain all records from the first DataFrame plus a column indicating whether the Person is a member of the organization at the time of the request (`REQUEST_DATE`) or not.

```
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
|USER_NAME|       REQUEST_DATE| USER_STATUS    |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
|     Mark|2018-02-20 00:00:00| Our user       |
|     Alex|2018-03-01 00:00:00| Not our user   |
|      Bob|2018-03-01 00:00:00| Our user       |
|     Mark|2018-07-01 00:00:00| Not our user   |
|     Kate|2018-07-01 00:00:00| No Information |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
```

**CODE:**

```
val df1: DataFrame  = Seq(
    ("Mark", "2018-02-20 00:00:00"),
    ("Alex", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Bob", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Mark", "2018-07-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Kate", "2018-07-01 00:00:00")
).toDF("USER_NAME", "REQUEST_DATE")

df1.show()

val df2: DataFrame  = Seq(
    ("Alex", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "OUT"),
    ("Bob", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-05 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Mark", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-03-01 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Mark", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2018-08-01 00:00:00", "OUT"),
    ("Meggy", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "OUT")
).toDF("NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "STATUS")

df2.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you stumble at a certain point? It's hard to help with a question like this without just providing the whole answer which wouldn't be of much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class UserAndRequest(
                           USER_NAME:String,
                           REQUEST_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           START_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           END_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           STATUS:String,
                           REQUEST_ID:Long
                         )

val joined : Dataset[UserAndRequest] = df1.withColumn("REQUEST_ID", monotonically_increasing_id).
  join(df2,$"USER_NAME" === $"NAME", "left").
  as[UserAndRequest]

val lastRowByRequestId = joined.
  groupByKey(_.REQUEST_ID).
  reduceGroups( (x,y) =>
    if (x.REQUEST_DATE.getTime > x.END_DATE.getTime && x.END_DATE.getTime > y.END_DATE.getTime) x else y
  ).map(_._2)

def logic(status: String): String = {
  if (status == "IN") "Our user"
  else if (status == "OUT") "not our user"
  else "No Information"
}

val logicUDF = udf(logic _)

val finalDF = lastRowByRequestId.withColumn("USER_STATUS",logicUDF($"REQUEST_DATE"))
```

which yield :

[image: result]

Comment: Hello! :) Right now I am tring to test code with your logic. In the final result which I want, count of records must be the same as in first dataframe. I am confused with second step. When I group by users it mean that the count would be less, right? Can you show how looks like code of 2nd step?

Comment: hey, are you still interested in that ? I have more time now, I can solve it.

Comment: Hello! :) I steal need help. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the long answer. Only now I was able to check your code. Unfortunately I'm having difficulty in code of `lastRowByRequestId`. In IDEA I see error in syntax. For example here `groupByKey(_.REQUEST_ID)` IDEA say me `cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_ID`. By the way, why you use `DataSet`? In post as you can see I use `DataFrame`.

Comment: my code takes 2 `DataFrame` as input and outputs a `DataFrame`. The reasons I use `Dataset`: 1. They're awesome cause they're `DataFrame` enhanced : they're typesafe. 2. the `reduceGroups` that I use in my code is from the Dataset API and make my code possible, it would be pain in the ass to do without it. 
About your IDE problem : I am 100 % my code is working, so if you're not running exactly my code, try to copy paste it exactly mine. Otherwise, make sure you're using Spark 2.+

Comment: Hello! I steal tring to run your code. I have error in `finalDF`: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. Also I don't notice it at start but why in your final result all data without time? It's important to have time. Can you help me please?